# Export data into Hive from a node without Hadoop(HDFS) installed

Tags: hadoop, export, hdfs

Is it possible to export data from a node that has not hadoop(HDFS) or Sqoop installed to a Hive server?
I would read the data from a source which could be Mysql or just files in some directory and then use the Hadoop core classes or something like Sqoop to export the data into my Hadoop cluster.
I am programming in Java.

Comment: DOes that node have hive or no hadoop ecosystems?I dint understand

Comment: Hi K S, yes that node does not have any Hive or Hadoop related software installed. I am guessing it is not possible to export data without them installed but wanted to make sure.

Comment: So, Is it like a data file in some node which has connectivity to hadoop cluster edge node ?

Comment: yes, exactly. I want to read a plain .txt file in a node which has a connection/access to a Hadoop cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are final destination is a hive table. I would suggest the following :

1. Create a hive final table.
2. use the following command to load data from the other node

   ```
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '<full local path>/kv1.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE table_name;
   ```

refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted)

Using Java , You could use JSCH lib to invoke these shell commands or so .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks K S, I will try it out. Also do you think it's a good idea vs just installing Hadoop locally?

Comment: It depends on the use case. There might be cases where loading data from edge node is required.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will probably install hadoop. It seems like calling the Hive cluster can become hard to debug. Instead of looking at one place you will have to look at 2 places.